# Dotvvm Repeater nested in Repeater

Tags: dotvvm

I like to use 2 dot:repeater(s) nested in one dothtml
example :

```
<dot:Repeater DataSource="{value: Projects}">
    <div class="project">
        <dot:LinkButton Click="{command: _root.RedirectToTasks(Id)}">{{value: Title}}</dot:LinkButton>
        <dot:Repeater DataSource="{value: _parent.Tasks}" WrapperTagName="table">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{value: Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{value: Completed ? ("Finished: " + CompletionDate) : "Not yet"}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <dot:LinkButton Text="Done"
                                        Click="{command: CompleteTask()}"
                                        Visible="{value: !Completed}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </dot:Repeater>
    </div>
</dot:Repeater>
```

i try  different options for the _parent. in the task part, but i don't get it working.  in other frameworks it is possible to alias the main repeater 
example: 'DataSource="{value: Projects}" as project' and then its possible in the nested repeater to use 'DataSource="{value: project.Tasks}"'  does someone know how to get this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner `Repeater`, you can use just `{value: Tasks}`, or alternatively `{value: _this.Tasks}`.

There is also a second caveat in the code: the `RenderWrapperTag="table"` is not a good idea if you don't have the `tbody` element. Some browsers will try to add the missing `tbody` and can break the DOM structure and cause the `Repeater` to stop working.

In general, you want to place the `Repeater` inside the `<table>` element and use `RenderWrapperTag="tbody"`:

```
<table>
    <dot:Repeater DataSource="{value: Tasks}" WrapperTagName="tbody">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>{{value: Title}}</td>
                <td>{{value: Completed ? ("Finished: " + CompletionDate) : "Not yet"}}</td>
                <td>
                    <dot:LinkButton Text="Done"
                                    Click="{command: CompleteTask()}"
                                    Visible="{value: !Completed}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </dot:Repeater> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this will work, i think WrapperTagName="tbody" do the trick, in my orginal code i use the  <tbody> tags.(i changed the code for the question to the objects which are used in the sample projects)